# UWP. Как реализовать подписку в приложении?

Tags: windowsphone, uwp

1. Как добавить в свое универсальное приложение возможность покупки подписки на определенный функционал? Т.е. некоторые функции в приложении становились бы доступны только при покупке подписки и на определенный период.
2. Будет ли подписка действовать на всех устройствах, где установлена программа?

Comment: не обращай внимания, мне -4 влепили. Якобы за то что тема не подходит сообществу. Спросил где это написано в правилах. Молчат)

Comment: Судя по всему, если ваш вопрос о задаче, которая как и большинство в программировании имеет несколько решений, каждое со своими плюсами и минусами. То такой вопрос здесь размещать нельзя? Хм... Зачем тогда такой ресурс? Это очень напрягает.

Comment: Причина закрытия неточна. Скорее вопрос "слишком обширен". Уточните, в чем именно вы видите проблему? @AlexeyVladimirovich: Покажете свой вопрос?

Comment: Вот мой вопрос : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438891/Вопрос-на-собеседовании

Comment: Единственное, что могу посоветовать из комментария - копайте отсюда https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn632430.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это все написано в документации:
Смотрите [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn532254.aspx) о том, как реализовать в приложении покупки.

После успешной покупки, задать Тип bool в `RoamingSettings` в True. Проверять, чтобы включить функции.

Смотрите [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx) по `RoamingSettings` документации